# Сравнение строковых данных сделанных в массиве и в базе данных Realm

Tags: база-данных, ios, swift, сравнение, realm

Здравствуйте, мне необходимо сравнить строковых данные сделанные в массиве и в базе данных Realm. Имеется данный массив в коде:

```
let months_arr = ["Январь","Февраль","Март","Апрель","Май","Июнь","Июль","Август","Сентябрь","Октябрь","Ноябрь","Декабрь"]
```

Имеется созданная база данных Realm с элементами:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import UIKit

class EventsDB: Object {
@objc  dynamic var dataMonth = ""
@objc  dynamic var dataDay = ""
@objc  dynamic var desc = ""
@objc  dynamic var link = ""

}
```

(в базе данных уже записан в столбец dataMonth, значение "Апрель"

Необходимо сравнить строковые значения "Апрель" в months_arr и "Апрель" в dataMonth.

Я так понимаю для извлечения данных из базы мне придется делать что-то подобное?:

```
let dat = realm.objects(EventsDB)
let filter = dat.filter("dataMonth")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ваш ход мыслей верен. Нужно немного усовершенстовать ваш код:

```
let months = realm.objects(EbentsDB.self)
let results = months.filter($0.dataMonth == "Апрель")
```